# How am I supposed to register my company on the Apple Store? Am I?

Tags: apple-id

I need to buy an iMac for my company. Both me and my company are located in Italy.

I've noticed that on my personal account it doesn't let me enter my full company details (in particular the VAT number), so I guess I have to register a company account.

I've noticed there is supposedly a ["business site"](http://store.apple.com/it-business), but when I try to [register a new account](https://appleid.apple.com/account?&localang=IT-IT&app_id=2083&returnURL=http%3A%2F%2Fstore.apple.com%2Fit-business) it brings me back to the normal site where I enter personal data, without company name, VAT n. etc.

So, what am I supposed to do to buy something for my company, receiving a proper invoice?

Comment: _I was unsure if this was in-topic or not, but looking [at the help](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), there's **"Apple services including iTunes Connect (selling music, books, apps)"**, and I guess the Apple Store counts as an Apple service._

Comment: Mentioning your country might be helpful, the same problem may not exist in all regions of the world.  However, I think the simplist thing to do is just call apple for help.  https://www.apple.com/contact/  i've had very good luck just giving apple a call.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to: https://ecommerce.apple.com to register as company and buy for company.